# Regex to capture 2 bits of data in - ABC:(anything)

Tags: c#, regex, .net-7.0

I need to parse (extract data - don't need to replace anything).

Test string: `MAIN_HEADER:(ANOTHER_HEADER([DUMDUM:(BAH_123),OOPS,YEAH:(GAGA)]))`
need to output:

- First component:
  `MAIN_HEADER` - only caps alpha and underscore
- Second component:
  `ANOTHER_HEADER:([DUMDUM:(BAH_123),OOPS,YEAH:(GAGA)])` - caps alpha, numbers, square and round brackets, commas, colons in any combination

I can extract second component with `^\(([a-zA-Z0-9_:,\(\)\[\]]*)\)$` but I don't know how to do 2 different matches to split components.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How well did it work? Is there anything after the test string, i.e., what signifies the end of the test string? Are you wanting balanced brackets, i.e., what output for `MH(AH(123` or for `MH(AH(4(56))))7`?

Comment: all brackets are always closed, but i dont want it recursive - i just need to split to 2 and rid off the separators - : and ()

Comment: Try this: `^([A-Z_]+):\s*([][A-Z0-9_(),:]+)`

Comment: almost! thank you.. i got this working: `^([A-Z_]+):\s*\(([][A-Z0-9_(),:]+)\)` make it an answer ill mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to extract 2 capture group as desired:

```bash
^([A-Z_]+):\s*\(([][A-Z0-9_(),:]+)\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8hefDR/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`:
- `([A-Z_]+)`: Match 1+ of uppercase letters or `_` in capture group #1
- `:\s*`: Match `:` followed by 0 or more whitespaces
- `\(`: Match literal `(`
- `([][A-Z0-9_(),:]+)`: Match 1+ of uppercase letters or `_` or digits or `(` or `)` or `[` or `]` or `,` or `:` in capture group #2
- `\)`: Match literal `)`